# Hyper-V - Network Switch when travelling?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I use a laptop that runs some VMs (in Hyper-V) e.g. SQL Server.

**I need the host (laptop) to have persistent network connectivity to the VMs, even when traveling, and might not have an internet connection.**

- On my laptop, the **'Default Switch' is missing** (Win11 Pro, latest
  updates installed) - I have spent days troubleshooting this, and I'm
  not the only one, and got nowhere with it, so I'm hoping someone can
  think of another way.
- If I create an **'Internal Switch'**, then it fails to automatically get
  DHCP (which means that if the laptop loses internet or the network
  changes (including WiFi/wired), then I have to reconfigure the VM
  each time).
- If I create an **'External Switch'**, then I need to bind it to the
  WiFi/wired adapter (not ideal), which then creates a bridge - and I
  have noticed that it severely impacts the host network connectivity -
  web pages take forever to load.

Comment: You need a working Default Switch to provide internal NAT which is what is required here. Consider doing a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the option to Keep Everything.  Other users already tried DISM / SFC.   This is a bit of a shot in the dark but it might work

Comment: Already tried DISM / SFC, and just done the Windows 11 Repair Install as per your recommendation.The 'Default Switch' does not work (VMs get 169.x.x.x IP addresses), and then the 'Default Switch' disappears after the first reboot, never to be seen again

Comment: An _Internal Switch_ is exactly for this purpose, but you’ll want to use static IP addresses for both VMs and the virtual adapter in the host OS. The _Internal Switch_ will be entirely unaffected by external connectivity changes. You can have it in addition to the _Default Switch_.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

I came across an article on this website: https://www.theictguy.co.uk/fixed-hyper-v-default-switch-repeated-create-delete-cycles/

And I was finally able to fix the 'Default Switch' by doing the following:

1. WIN + R > Enter 'msconfig'
2. Go to Services Tab, check 'Hide all Microsoft services'
3. Disable services that may have something to do with networking and/or network adapters (for me this was Acrylic DNS Proxy, Zero Tier, VPNs, TeamViewer, etc)
4. From Start Menu, type 'Turn Windows Features On or Off', find Hyper-V and **uncheck** it (this will not delete your VMs, your data and configuration will be unaffected)
5. Reboot
6. Once rebooted, repeat Step 4 but this time **check** Hyper-V
7. Reboot
8. Now you should have a persistent 'Default Switch' in Hyper-V, and you may begin working your way through your disabled services list (from Step 3) and re-enable them one by one (with a reboot in between, to make sure that they do not break the Default Switch again)

Hope this will be of use to someone in the future.